# Incorrect shape of array after using tf.stack to stack three arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to concatenate arrays together. Here is my attempt:

```
rgb = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 672, 672, 3])
r, g, b = tf.split(rgb, 3, 3)
bgr = tf.stack(
    [
        b-23.5,
        g-30.6,
        r-40.1
    ],3)

print "rgb :", rgb
print "r :",r 
print "bgr :", bgr
```

However, I am getting the incorrect shape for `bgr`. Instead of `(?, 672, 672, 3, 1)` I want the same shape as rgb, i.e. `(?, 672, 672, 3)`

```
rgb : Tensor("mul:0", shape=(?, 672, 672, 3), dtype=float32)
r : Tensor("split:0", shape=(?, 672, 672, 1), dtype=float32)
bgr : Tensor("stack:0", shape=(?, 672, 672, 3, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [tf.concat()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat)

```
bgr = tf.concat([b-23.5,
                 g-30.6,
                 r-40.1], axis=3)
```

It concatenates a list of tensors along dimension `axis` without introducing new dimension. Tensors to be concatenated should have same shape except the dimension `axis` they are concatenated along.